# How to delete Rect object after intersect in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I would like to delete some Rect object after IntersectsWith another one.
For example:

```
if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
{
    rect1.Remove()?!
}
```

How could I do that? Those rects are in myCanvas.Children, but I don't know how to get their index for `myCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(index)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
{
    myCanvas.Children.Remove(rect1);
}
```

That way you don't need to find the index first.

In case you need the index use [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590018(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
{
    var index = myCanvas.IndexOf(rect1);
    if(index > -1)
    {
        myCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```